# Adobe Illustrator CC crashes on startup

Tags: crash, adobe-illustrator

I have a problem with Adobe Illustrator CC for a day.

**Adobe Illustrator CC crashes every time I launch it.**

When I launch it, opens the normal app window with a grey background. It sits there for a second then crashes with no dialogue box!

I have tried:

1. Uninstall Adobe Illustrator CC and re-install it again.
2. Uninstall Adobe Illustrator CC & running Adobe CC Cleaner Tool and re-install it again.
3. Disable Graphics Card And open Adobe Illustrator CC
4. Delete Adobe Creative files and uninstall it with Adobe Illustrator and re-install them again.

> ### New Update [11 Sep 2020]: The only way was to reinstall Windows 10. Thanks

---

- Adobe Illustrator CC (2018)
- 64-Bit - Windows 10
- Graphics Card: AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M445 | RAM: 8iGB

Comment: You say, “I have tried everything”.   It would help if you listed at least some of the things you have tried, so people don’t waste their time (and yours) suggesting approaches you’ve already eliminated.    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You bought a product from a company and it does not work... did you try asking said company for help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue 2 years ago, Try to reinstall windows!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and resolved it by running Adobe's CC cleaner and doing a clean install.

[This page – Use the Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool
to solve installation problems](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html) provides some instruction.